# How to update a textarea with line breaks through Ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am desperately trying to update a textarea with Ajax:

application.js:

```
$("#invoice_project_id").change(function() {
    var value=$(this).val();
    $.get('/invoices/get_recipient', {project_id= : value}  function(response) {
        $('#invoice_recipient').val(response);
    })
});​
```

get_recipient.js:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("<%= @recipient %>");
```

The code stops working when a value that contains line breaks is being inserted into the textarea.

For example, I get this on my console when inserting a simple one liner value:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("123 Evergreen Terrasse");
```

Which is correct and works perfectly.

But, when trying to insert a value that contains a line break, I get this on my console:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("65341 Bruen Brooks
East Charityville");
```

(Note the line break after `Brooks` that probably causes JavaScript to terminate the code.)

Is there any way to fix this, perhaps by removing the line breaks from the values?

Comment: This doesn't look like a Ruby or Rails problem, but instead is strictly limited to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, looks like I have found a solution here, thanks to [this blog post](http://databasically.com/2009/03/18/updating-textarea-with-ajax-unterminated-string-literal/).

Instead of this:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("<%= @recipient %>");
```

I am now doing this:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("<%= @recipient.to_s.gsub!(/\n/, '\n') %>");
```

The `gsub!()` function simply replaces the newline characters with other newline characters (?) and, surprisingly, it works, even though it has some weaknesses of its own.

Thanks everybody for helping me out here!

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems weird but I can't figure out how you get this:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("65341 Bruen Brooks
East Charityville");
```

Are you auto-generating your `javascript` code from other `server-side` code?

*(maybe your value is so long and cause this to happen but first time I see something like this)*

---

Seems that I answered to myself because you were doing that. So, my solution is simple but could help, why don't you put the long value first in a variable and then pass it to the `.val()` like this:

```
var longText = "this is a looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text that may cause problems"; 
$('#invoice_recipient').val(longText);
```

`longText` was obtained from `<%= @recipient %>` like this:

`var longText = "<%= @recipient %>";`

Doing this way you avoid any breakline that can generate your `server-side` value that causes problems to `javascript` code.

---

I made this for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/HssgJ/

As you can see, a long value is inside a `textbox`, doesn't matter the breaklines.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I could not get this to work on my machine though. I think I found a solution and posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val(encodeURIComponent("<%= @recipient %>"));
```

Although, not sure is what you are looking for.

Comment: This will add `%20` internally like `URL encode` to the recipient `string`. I am not sure if this could work cause I don't know if  `javascript` will render the value as `my string` or `my%20string` and  then you will need to do a `URL decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use squish

```
%{ Multi-line
   string }.squish                   # => "Multi-line string"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish